# Better way to give provide path of libraries while compiling in C++

Tags: c++, shell, boost, command-line

I pretty new to C++. I was wondering, as what is considered generally a neat way to provide paths for various files/libraries while compiling or executing c++ codes.

For ex:
I have Boost libraries installed in some location on my system. Lets call it X
In order to execute anything I have to type in

```
c++ -I LongpathWhichisX/to/boost_1_60_0 example.cpp -o example
```

Similarly, also Long path for the input file while executing the code.

Is there a better way to address it. Is it possible to create environment variables lets Y, which refers to path 'X'. And we can use following command to compile code

```
c++ -I Y/to/boost_1_60_0 example.cpp -o example
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way is to use build tools. For example you can use [Make](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_(software)). You define all your include paths (and other options) in the Makefile. In console you just have to call `make` to build your project or something like `make run` to run your project.

Answer (score 0):

The usual way is to make a Makefile where you can specify all needed paths and compile options in proper variables.

If you don't want/need a Makefile and rather want to run compiler from command-line, then you may use the CPATH environment variable to specify a colon-separated list of paths to include files.

Answer (score 0):

This is a broad question but the other answers highlight the most important step. It is essential to learn build tools like make because they will make it easier to build your projects during development and for others to build it later. In the modern programming age though this is not enough. If you are using something like Boost (which targets many platforms) you will probably want to make your build cross-platform as well. For this you would use either [cmake](https://cmake.org/) or [autotools](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/GNU-Build-System.html#GNU-Build-System) which both have scripts that make it much easier to locate the Boost libraries (and others).

Any other build systems, in my opinion, are a pain and are the bane of maintainers of Linux distributions. CMake used to be in that catergory but it has gained wide acceptance now. CMake targets building cross-platform projects across operating systems (Windows and Unixes) better (again in my opinion) because it attempts to provide the native build system on each platform (for example: Visual Studio in Windows, Make on all Unices, XCode on Mac). The autotools instead target the Unix environment with much greater depth (you have a bit of a harder time on Windows, but you can target embedded Unix systems to high end Unix server systems with much more flexibility).

**Note:** Autotools support for cross-compiling is superior in almost every way to other solutions. I always cringe when I download something that needs to be cross compiled for Arm Linux and it uses some weird build system. Funnily enough, boost is one of these.

This is a bit of a long winded answer. In summary, it is essential that you learn a build system for native development. It is part of your skill set and until you have that skill you can't really contribute to open-source projects or even your employer developing closed-source projects.